# file copy speed using pycurl and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, libcurl, pycurl

I have a script that copies 50 or so files linked to by urls. The files average about 20 MB in size and I am using `pycurl` from within a custom `file_copy` function to copy them. I started several `file_copy` threads in order to increase speed, but with either 4 or 8 threads I only see about a 33% speed improvement versus using a single thread.

Are threaded `pycurl` functions the best choice for this use case?

Comment: Threads in Python have their performance issues, but my biggest hunch here is that your operations are IO-bound anyway.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, this was it. I was already near max on my bandwidth so there was not much room for improvement with threading. I was able to increase the bandwidth, and multiple threads (up to about 16) now make a significant performance improvement (~10X) versus a single-threaded approach.